# Way to make <td>s behave like divs and ignore <tr>s?

Tags: html, css

I have a table with 2 rows of 5 columns.

For mobile optimisation, I want the `<td>`s to behave like floated divs give me 2 columns of 5 rows.

To that effect I have created:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   table td {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

This works but I still get a seperation where the two `<tr>`s meet. Instead of 2 columns of 5 I get a column of 6 and a column of 4.

See fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/xjzpaudr/20/

Would anyone know if there's a way to remove the `<tr>` without affecting their child elements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding `table tr { display: inline; }` in your media query:

```
@media (max-width: 600px) {
   table tr { display: inline; }
   table td {
        float: left;
        width: 50%;
    }
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/xjzpaudr/21/

Answer (score 0):

Althought I can't think of a possible way to do this with HTML table, CSS3 Flexbox combined with CSS media query could do the trick.

Here is a snippet on which I set the media query to break to 5 rows of 2 columns when screen size go bellow 600px (as an example)

Try it in full page and resize the browser under 600px to see the result.

CSS-Tricks website explain it very well : https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

CSS Flexbox are supported by modern browsers (IE 11, Edge, Chrome, Firefox, Safari, Android, ... http://caniuse.com/#search=flexbox)

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  justify-content: center;
}

.item {
  border: 1px solid red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 19%;
  display: inline-flex;
}

@media (max-width: 600px) {
  .item {
    width: 49%;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="item">1</div>
  <div class="item">2</div>
  <div class="item">3</div>
  <div class="item">4</div>
  <div class="item">5</div>
  <div class="item">6</div>
  <div class="item">7</div>
  <div class="item">8</div>
  <div class="item">9</div>
  <div class="item">10</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Remember that the question posed states that the DOM is made up of a table with two rows of five cells each.